# Why is max number ignoring two-digit numbers?

Tags: list, file, python-3.x, max

At the moment I am saving a set of variables to a text file. I am doing following to check if my code works, but whenever I use a two-digit numbers such as 10 it would not print this number as the max number.

If my text file looked like this.

```
tom:5
tom:10
tom:1
```

It would output 5 as the max number.

```
name = input('name')
score = 4
if name == 'tom':
    fo= open('tom.txt','a')
    fo.write('Tom: ')
    fo.write(str(score ))
    fo.write("\n")
    fo.close()

if name == 'wood':
    fo= open('wood.txt','a')
    fo.write('Wood: ')
    fo.write(str(score ))
    fo.write("\n")
    fo.close()

tomL2 = []
woodL2 = []

fo = open('tom.txt','r')
tomL = fo.readlines()
tomLi = tomL2 + tomL
fo.close
tomLL=max(tomLi)
print(tomLL)


fo = open('wood.txt','r')
woodL = fo.readlines()
woodLi = woodL2 + woodL
fo.close
woodLL=max(woodLi)
print(woodLL)
```

Comment: You are comparing strings, not numbers.  You need to convert them into `float`s before using `max`.

Comment: Ok so something like this: keys.sort(key=float)

Comment: It's not that simple.  As far as Python is concerned, a string is just an amorphous sequence of characters: it doesn't understand whether there's a human-readable number inside.  In order to extract that number you need to explicitly [parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) the string.

Comment: thankyou very much has worked a treat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing strings, not numbers. You need to convert them into numbers before using `max`.  For example, you have:

```
tomL = fo.readlines()
```

This contains a list of strings:

```
['tom:5\n', 'tom:10\n', 'tom:1\n']
```

Strings are ordered [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) (much like how words would be ordered in an English dictionary).  If you want to compare numbers, you need to turn them into numbers first:

```
tomL_scores = [int(s.split(':')[1]) for s in tomL]
```

The parsing is done in the following way:

- `….split(':')` separates the string into parts using a colon as the delimiter:

  `'tom:5\n'` becomes `['tom', '5\n']`
- `…[1]` chooses the *second* element from the list:

  `['tom', '5\n']` becomes `'5\n'`
- `int(…)` converts a string into an integer:

  `'5\n'` becomes `5`
- The list comprehension `[… for s in tomL]` applies this sequence of operations to every element of the list.

Note that `int` (or similarly `float`) are rather picky about what it accepts: it must be in the form of a valid numeric literal or it will be rejected with an error (although preceding and trailing whitespace is allowed).  This is why you need `….split(':')[1]` to massage the string into a form that it's willing to accept.

This will yield:

```
[5, 10, 1]
```

Now, you can apply `max` to obtain the largest score.

As a side-note, the statement

```
fo.close
```

will *not* close a file, since it doesn't actually *call* the function.  To call the function you must enclose the arguments in parentheses, even if there are none:

```
fo.close()
```